# BootstrapVue Table not displaying data

Tags: vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I am trying to use the bootstrapVue table found [here](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table/)

If i use their example exactly the table works great.

```
  <b-table striped hover :items="items"></b-table>
```

However once i use

```
<b-table striped hover :fundingInstructions="fundingInstructions"></b-table>
```

My table does not display and when i look in the dev tools i see that my table has [object,Object] for each object i return from my api.
[image]
 If i console log my data i see an array [] with multiple objects. How do i get the table to display my data?

```
 const items = [
  { isActive: true,  date:'10/20/2018', amount:'$4568.00', city:'FL Palm Beach' },
  { isActive: false,  date:'10/21/2018', amount:'$789.23', city:'FL Daytona Beach' },
  { isActive: false,  date:'10/21/2018', amount:'$999.99', city:'FL Key West' },
  { isActive: true,  date:'10/22/2018', amount:'$589.00', city:'FL Deltona' }
]

 export default {
    data() {
      return {
        fundingInstructions : [],
         fields: [ 'subMerchantName', 'fundsTransferId', 'amount' ,'accType', 'submitDate' ],
        items: items
      }
      },
         methods:{
           async GetFundingInstructionInfo(){
             this.fundingInstructions = await api.getAllFundingInstructions()
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so i figured out what the problem was and hence the solution. 
In the table html it should look like this

```
  <b-table striped hover :items="fundingInstructions"></b-table>
```

It seems that items is a key term and your collection goes in the quotation. That's it!

Comment: JESUS! I would've never figured this out, I've been stuck with this for over half an hour, they really should've picked more clear naming!

Comment: Thank you. Their documentation is definitely faulty with :items="items". I had changed both because it was not clear. You resolved my issue.